# Reset MySQL 5 root password on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, password, root

I just installed MySQL 5 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.1), set a password and forgot it. I tried to follow this tutorial: http://blog.innovativethought.net/2007/05/17/resetting-your-forgotten-mysql-password/ but when I do:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --ignore-grant-table
```

it says:

> touch:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.err:
>   Permission denied chown:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.err:
>   Permission denied Starting mysqld
>   daemon with databases from
>   /usr/local/mysql/data
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line
>   380:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.err:
>   Permission denied rm:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.pid:
>   Permission denied
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line
>   388:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.err:
>   Permission denied STOPPING server from
>   pid file
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.pid
>   tee:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.err:
>   Permission denied 090920 16:14:34
>   mysqld ended tee:
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.err:
>   Permission denied

and when I do (using **sudo**):

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --ignore-grant-table
```

it says:

> Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
>   STOPPING server from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.pid
>   090920 16:15:36  mysqld ended

Why the heck does it stop? Can someone explain it?

Thanks in advance.

Oh,

- I'm NOT using Mac OS X Server.
- I've set the password in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the server before restarting it in safemode.

```
sudo kill -9 $(cat /usr/local/mysql/data/unknown-00-24-8d-0d-d4-cf.lan.pid)
```

Then follow (as root, or with sudo) the instructions.

Comment: Don't `kill -9` unless all else fails.

Comment: I agree, it was the short way :P

Comment: This won't work - launchd will start a new process as soon as it's killed.  You need to use launchctl to stop the process and then start your own.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem and solved it. With MySQL 5, do

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe5 --skip-grant-tables
```